# Getting URLs from search results

Tags: c#, computer-science, web, internationalization

After 1 months research I basically give up on getting all URL's from a search results programmatically,

I looked at Google Search API to find a way to get millions of search results "URL's" to be specific to a text file or something relative but no success, but I am 100% there must be a way or trick of doing it.

Real Question :

Is there anyway programmatically or manually I can get 1000+ search results (URLs using search query e.g. "Apple" returns million of results on google and I want as much as possible URLs of them results in a text file)

Note :

Don't care for any specific search engine or programming language or technique or software or just point me to right direction, but yeah I tried it with google API i can't get more then 100 results at all.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a better way to achieve it.

Comment: See my answer to : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/164577/finding-database-issue-for-iphone-app

Comment: @Morons sorry but your answer ain't helpful

Comment: @LokiAstari I want to get all URLs for a specific query for whole web :)

Comment: @tereško: No. That is a step in what you are trying to achieve. What are you actually trying to achieve. Maybe there is a better way to achieve your end result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an open source project that you could use to model what you want.  It is in Java, but the source looks well commented.

http://code.google.com/p/google-search-java-sdk/

Comment: it won't gonna return thousands of results back or will it :)

Comment: After reading through the methods and such, it looks like you can page through the results.  So you will get x results at a time, and then you can ask for page 2, page 3, etc.